# @Html.ValidationMessageFor() required field displaying message when populated

Tags: vb.net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I am currently using ASP.net MVC (VB).

I have a model with the following property:

`<Required(ErrorMessage:="Contact name is required")>`
`Public Property contact_name() As String`

In my controller method (accepts a post request and binds various parameters to the model) I set contact_name from two other parameters :

`model.contact_name = first_name + " " + last_name`

I return to my view containing a form which has an input field with a value of `model.contact_name`
and I use the tag

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.contact_name`

The problem is that the error message is always displayed, unless the POST request has the parameter: `contact_name`. Even if the error message is displayed, if I submit the form the model is valid. (`modelState.isValid == true`).

Since I set the value of model.contact_name and pass the model to the view, technically, the model state should be valid, the required property contact_name is not null or blank and the validationMessageFor the contact_name property should not be appearing.

Why it is appearing?
How do I stop it from appearing if the value of model.contact_name is not blank?

Comment: Because if you submit your form without a value for `contact_name`, then the `DefaultModelBinder` adds a `ModelStateError`. Just changing the value of the property does not change `ModelState`

Comment: Does `model.contact_name = first_name + " " + last_name` really make sense? If you are always going to put a space between those other two values then that seems to imply that they are required, so why not just put `Required` attributes on those two properties and not on `contact_name`, given that those are the ones that the user can actually affect?

Comment: By the way, you can obviously use whatever naming convention you like but, given that `ContactName` is what would be used throughout the Framework and any third-party components you may use, why use `contact_name` for a property?

Comment: @StephenMuecke when I submit the form, the contact_name has a value, the ModelState is valid, but the error message appears on the form. 
I ended up using javascript to add some front end validation and hid the error message if there is a value in the input field.

Comment: @jmcilhinney the parameters `first_name` and `last_name` are not always provided (not required), however if provided they should be used to populate a single field on the form. When the form is submitted, `contact_name` is required.  

The reason I used contact_name instead of contactName was to be consistent with the naming convention used in existing code.